# Composing a function from an uncurried function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to create a curriable function that returns whether or not the supplied length is equal to the length of the supplied string. I'd like it to work like this:

```
checkLength(3)('asdf') // => false
checkLength(4)('asdf') // => true
```

I initially tried this, but the argument order is reversed because it returns the curried `equals` function:

```
const checkLength = R.compose(R.equals(), R.prop('length'))
checkLength('asdf')(4)
```

I can fix by wrapping it in a function like this:

```
const checkLength = (len) => R.compose(R.equals(len), R.prop('length'))
```

But it seems like there would be a way to use the functional library to solve this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to go is to [`flip`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#flip) that function you found - unfortunately to work properly, we need to add a stage of uncurrying the composed function:

```
const checkLength = R.flip(R.uncurryN(2, R.compose(R.equals, R.prop('length'))))
checkLength(4)('asdf') // => true
```

An alternative solution would be to use the [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#useWith) function:

```
const checkLength = R.useWith(R.equals, [R.identity, R.prop('length')]);
checkLength(4)('asdf') // => true
```

Comment: One day I replaced all my ramda code since vanilla JS is much more maintainable `const checkLength = len => str => str.length === len;` :-) (+1 still though)

Comment: Did you try the code that uses `flip`? It doesn't work for me, and it seems that argument flipping isn't quite what we want.

Comment: The `useWith` solution is clever. I wouldn't have thought of that. It seems regular JS may be the clearest.

Comment: @Ben: Oops, I didn't try, and naively assumed that `flip` would work on curried functions. But yes, flipping arguments is *exactly* what we want - it's `checkLength('asdf')(4)` vs `checkLength(4)('asdf')`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now understand how it can be done in Ramda and will be using vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261065/1243641) from [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572) is just what I was going to suggest for a points-free solution.  But as is seen often, points-free should not be used for its own sake.  When it makes things clearer, by all means use it.  And before ES6, that was fairly common.  Fat arrows and other cleaner syntax are tipping the balance back again.

I might still write this with Ramda's [`curry`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) function, as that offers some additional flexibility:

```
const checkLength = curry((len, str) => str.length === len);
checkLength(3)('abcd'); //=> checkLength(3, 'abcd'); //=> false
```

This is definitely cleaner and easier to read than a [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) solution.  You can see this at work in **[the Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/kgneGj)**.